# Hide search box but allow search in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a way to hide the search box in select2 js, but allow the search option like in the ordinary select box?

Example:

Type 's' in keyboard it should move to the result which has started with 's' in it(select box options).

To hide the search box, the code what i have used is

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $(".my_country").select2({minimumResultsForSearch: -1});
});
```

Fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfv62/2/

Comment: put the entire useful code on JsFiddle

Comment: @florin.prisecariu, I have added the jsfiddle

Comment: after how many typed letters would you like to hide the input box? after first letter ?

Comment: I do not want the input field for the select box, used for search in the select2, but want the search to happen as ordinary selectbox

Answer (score 3):

you do this using css:

```
.select2-search {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**position:absolute** will detatch the search box from its place and allow the options to take the top spot.

**opacity:0** will hide the appearance of search box.

**z-index:-1** will make search box go below the options. Thus on clicking obove search box area will click on option instead of the search box.